# Cgywin - issue setting /var permissions for ssh

Tags: windows, cygwin, ssh

I am having trouble to install ssh via Cygwin on my latest new Windows machine with the latest Cygwin version.

```
*** Warning: The permissions on the directory /var are not correct.
*** Warning: They must match the regexp d..x..x..[xt]
*** ERROR: Problem with /var directory. Exiting.
$ ls -al /
d--S--s--x+ 1 Matthias Administrators      0 2010-12-06 07:52 var
```

How can I modify the rights on the directory so that it fits the above mentioned regular expression?

Comment: I ended up copying the /tmp directory as a workaround as it has the right rights, but I would still like to know the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it (do both):

```
chmod 755 /var
chmod ug-s /var
```

Comment: I ended up with -S instead of x when running this and thus the sshd would not install.

Comment: @weismat: Try also doing `chmod ug-s /var`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I also had to execute

```
chmod 775 /var/*
```

to get `ssh-host-config` to work.